# CasperJS cannot set window.navigator object

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs, headless-browser

Trying to scrape a web page with CasperJS. Webpage checks to see if the browser is an IE 6/7.

Passing an userAgent with casperjs doesn't seem to satisfy its condition. UserAgent passed: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)
Following is the check being made by the page to determine the browser

```
agt = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
browserType = navigator.appName;

if( ((browserType.indexOf("xplorer") != -1) 
    && (agt.indexOf("msie 6.") != -1))
    ||  ((browserType.indexOf("xplorer") != -1) 
    && (agt.indexOf("msie 7.") != -1)) )
{

}
else
{
    alert("This "+ browserType + " Version is not supported by this application. Please use Internet Explorer  6.x or Internet Explorer 7.x.");
    window.close();
}
```

Following is the debug info from casperjs.

> [info] [remote] [alert] This Netscape Version is not supported by this applicat
>   on. Please use Internet Explorer  6.x or Internet Explorer 7.x.
>
> [warning] [phantom] Loading resource failed with status=fail (HTTP 200): http://

Any pointers on setting `window.navigator` object before page redirect?

Comment: Also keep an eye on the TrifleJS project ( http://triflejs.org/ ). It is not working with CasperJS yet (which is why I am not posting this as an answer!), but that is one of their goals. (It can emulate IE7, so might be your best choice, if you are not tied to CasperJS.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `navigator` properties are read only, so you cannot set them and PhantomJS doesn't provide a capability to set it.

The solution is to make a proxy of the `navigator` object. The old `navigator` stays in the background, but it is replaced with a new one that behaves the same, but with an `appName` of "Internet Explorer". This whole bootstrapping process can be triggered from the [`page.initialized`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-initialized) callback.

```
casper.on('page.initialized', function(){
    this.evaluate(function(){
        (function(oldNav){
            var newNav = {};
            [].forEach.call(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(navigator), function(prop){
                if (prop === 'appName') {
                    Object.defineProperty(newNav, prop, {
                        enumerable: false,
                        configurable: false,
                        writable: false,
                        value: 'Internet Explorer'
                    });
                } else {
                    Object.defineProperty(newNav, prop, {
                        enumerable: false,
                        configurable: false,
                        get: function(){
                            return oldNav[prop];
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
            window.navigator = newNav;
        })(window.navigator);
    });
});
```

The same goes for vanilla PhantomJS with the `page.onInitialized` event handler.

Working around the browser detection doesn't guarantee that the page works or looks good on PhantomJS. There is a reason some pages are "optimized" for IE and the reason is most of the time that some propietary features where used that are not there in other browsers.

Comment: Mine didn't work in page initialized, but worked in evaluate. Thanks anyways. Tried on phantomjs.